# How do I set an object's identifier to the content of a string?

Tags: c#, uwp

I am making a hangman app in UWP. I would like to create a number of rectangles equal to the length of the word (for the bars underneath the letters). I already have a loop that creates a number of columns equal to the length of the word. Unlike the columns, the rectangles I create will need to have identifiers so I can set their properties. Is it possible to set the rectangles' identifiers to Bar1, Bar2, etc. by setting them to the content of a string? Here's what I imagine:

```
for (int counter = 0; counter < stupidWord.Length; counter++)
{
    WordGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition());
    string barName = "Bar" + counter;
    Rectangle barName = new Rectangle();
}
```

The rectangles' identifiers would be whatever barName is equal to at the time of their construction.

Comment: Have you considered creating an array or `List<Rectangle>` to store all of your rectangles so that they can access them by index?

Comment: Maybe you can also use `Rectangle.Tag` property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The functionality you ask for, which is to access each individual Rectangle object independently (perhaps during runtime of your game) could be achieved by using a Collection to store the objects:

```
List<Rectangle> rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
for(int i = 0; i < word.Length; i++)
{
    var rectangle = new Rectangle();
    rectangles.Add(rectangle);
}
```

You would then access each of these rectangles by looking them up at their index:

```
int indexOfCurrentGuessingChar = 1;
Rectangle currentRectangle = rectangles[indexOfCurrentGuessingChar];
//now i have retreived the rectangle of index 1, and can access its properties
currentRectangle.Width = 100;
```

That said, here is a possible solution for connection a Rectangle with an unique id:
To be able to connect each Rectangle object to an id a solution would be to create a class which has a property for the rectangle and for the id:

```
class Container
{
    public Rectangle Rectangle;
    public string Id;
}
```

Then use the Container class like this:

```
Container container = new Container();
container.Rectangle = new Rectangle();
container.Id = "bar1";
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Sorry for the late response; I thought I would get emailed when someone responded. I can't believe I didn't think of using a list and a foreach loop to refer to the rectangles before they have names.